# How to span a heading over multiple lines in a .adoc file?

Tags: asciidoc

Asciidoc ignores line breaks in paragraphs:

```
These lines
are actually
in the same paragraph
```

=>

> These lines are actually in the same paragraph

However, it does not do it for headings:

```
=== long heading
that I would like to 
span over multiple lines
in the .adoc file
```

=>

> ### long heading
>
> that I would like to 
>   span over multiple lines
>   in the .adoc file

But I want this:

> ### long heading that I would like to span over multiple lines in the .adoc file

So how do I place a heading on multiple lines in the file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is indeed not possible/not working for me. But some useful discussion about possible workarounds or a feature request is here: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/3627

Comment: sounds like a good solution but does not work for me

Answer (score 4):

Document and section titles in Asciidoc syntax must appear on a single line.

If you need to influence the presentation of the title, you might try inserting `<br>` tags at the appropriate locations in the title, as described here: [https://geekmusthave.com/?p=3160](https://web.archive.org/web/20190422125356/https://geekmusthave.com/?p=3160)